# Push file from HTTP server to client after submitting a form

Tags: html, c++, http

I have some HTTP server, written fully on C++, serving many HTML forms. Each form has one or several submit buttons. After processing next submit button, the server replies the client to be redirected to new (or current) HTML page displaying another form.

Today I need to add the following feature: the submit buttons should be processed as is, but in addition my server can generate some file with given file name to be downloaded by a user.

How it can be done using HTTP+HTML with minimal changes of the currently working project?

Comment: So a submit button is pressed and you need to return a file and also another form?  How are you going to return two HTTP responses to the same request?  You could return a page containing both the next form and also a link to download the file.  Or you could have the submit button make an ajax call to get the file and then do this submit - but that would download the file every single time.

Comment: This is the important point that submit button’s backend handler is only a creator of the wished file.

Comment: Can't avoid javascript. What you want to do is that in the response to the submit button the returned page has a hidden form, and some javascript to submit that form. That second form then ends up downloading the file. You might be able to avoid Javascript by returning a frame, with a hidden frame downloading the file, and the main content in the main frame.